# Mouse event in Static Body

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

I have the following logic in my game.

1. Shapes are displayed on top of the screen.  it should be static.
2. If click "A" letter shape(static), it should be falling down on the vehicle.
3. Vehicle should move on particular place.

When i click the static body, it does not detecting mouse up event.  If the shape is dynamic, it is working fine.

Can any one assist me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not say how you are detecting the shape that was clicked on, but I guess you are using the code from the Box2D testbed. If so, take a look at [the QueryCallback used there](https://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Testbed/Framework/Test.cpp#118), and you will see this:

```
if ( body->GetType() == b2_dynamicBody )
```

This is because that code was made to create a mouse joint to drag things around, and mouse joints will only affect dynamic bodies.

Comment: I did the logic using Joint.  Thanks for your reply.